# ERROR:Unexpected condition at file:[]Application terminating. informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I got this error:

> Service process [integrationServiceName] generated the following
>   output error: [ERROR:Unexpected condition at file:[]Application
>   terminating. Contact informatica Technical Support for assistance.]

every time that I try to run a workflow which includes
an Access DB source/target.ie. each time that in the session mapping there is an ODBC Connection to Access Driver. I manage to preview the data on client.
I created a DSN to the 64bit mod Administrator on Server.
I run the workflow and my session fails without logging errors.
I got only this one on the Administrator console and
First Error Code:36401..Execution terminated unexpextedly in run properties of session.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the Server Side DSN or Connection String. Did you trying connecting to the DSN manually on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the custom property in session config object as
OptimizeODBCRead=No;